# How to improve list items from a VirtualList

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

You see, actually I have a virtual list widget:

```
var list = new qx.ui.list.List().set({labelPath: "label"});
```

So I use a Json store for retrive the data from server:

```
var store = new qx.data.store.Json('my/resource/data.json');
store.bind("model", list, "model");
```

And that works. But I need list elements a bit more rich, with more that an icon, also a bit description and status. That data is at json returned by the server, but now can I custom the item elements to show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists as they are in *qooxdoo* use [qx.ui.form.ListItem](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.form.ListItem) by default. You can override this by the `createItem` in your list [delegate](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.ui.list.core.IListDelegate).

[This example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#data~ExtendedList.html) from the demobrowser shows how to use the delegate with `createItem` and `bindItem`.

What you need to do if you've real *custom* ideas on how the list item should look, is:

- Create a custom *ListItem* class that implements `qx.ui.form.IModel` (and probably include `qx.ui.form.MModelProperty`). Make use of properties and child controls. Maybe it's a good start to inherit from `qx.ui.form.ListItem` and override the layout/child controls, but you can also inherit from `qx.ui.core.Widget` - with the need to take care about *states*, etc.
- Style it like you desire using the theming mechanism.
- Use `setDelegate()` to override `createItem` and `bindItem` to wire the desired model properties to your custom list item.

As the question didn't go into detail further, that may give you a starting point.